# Django model form field initials not updating

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

Here my intention is to pass the `analysis_start_date` value as year and month only(%Y-%m),

below in my form class

```
allowed_date_formats = [
    '%m-%Y',
    '%Y-%m-%d',
    '%m/%d/%Y',
    '%m/%d/%y',
    '%Y-%m'
]

class PropertyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    analysis_start_date = forms.DateField(
        input_formats=allowed_date_formats,
        help_text="Choose the starting month",
    )
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.instance:
              date = self.instance.analysis_start_date
              kwargs.update(initial={
                  'analysis_start_date': date.strftime('%Y-%m')
              })
```

but in the output form it shows date including the day,
[image]

thanks in advance for any solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

solved it in the update view

```
def get_form(self):
        """Return an instance of the form to be used in this view.
        """
        form = super(PropertyUpdateView, self).get_form()
        analysis_start_date = form.initial.get("analysis_start_date")
        if analysis_start_date:
            form.initial['analysis_start_date'] = analysis_start_date.strftime("%Y-%m")
        return form
```